# Safe way to remove elements from a list in Perl?

Tags: perl

I'm having some weird results from this perl code - I need to delete several elements from a list of Association objects.

My approach is to scan the list once, push the matches to another array, then iterate that array and delete each one, but I haven't escaped the "don't delete while iterating pitfall".

Any ideas on how to avoid this?  Many thanks.

```
my @agentConfAssociationDeletionsList = (
    "AcceptTPCookie",
    "AgentNamesAreFQHostNames",
    "BadCssChars",
    "LogLocalTime"
);

#find associations to remove
my @associationsToRemove = ();
foreach my $association ($agentConf->GetAssociations()) {
    if ( grep {$_ eq $association->Name()} @agentConfAssociationDeletionsList) {
        print "pushing " . $association->Name() . "\n";
        push(@associationsToRemove, $association);
    }
}

#remove them
foreach my $association (@associationsToRemove) {
    print "removing association: " . $association->Name();
    agentConf->RemoveAssociation($association);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first loop is this:

```
my @associationsToRemove = ();
foreach my $association ($agentConf->GetAssociations()) {
    if ( grep {$_ eq $association->Name()} @agentConfAssociationDeletionsList) {
        print "pushing " . $association->Name() . "\n"; 
        push(@associationsToRemove, $association);  
    }
}
```

which is equivalent to this:

```
my @associationsToRemove = ();
my @associations = $agentConf->GetAssociations();
foreach my $association (@associations) {
    if ( grep {$_ eq $association->Name()} @agentConfAssociationDeletionsList) {
        print "pushing " . $association->Name() . "\n";
        push(@associationsToRemove, $association);
    }
}
```

So, GetAssociations() is called before the first iteration of the 
loop. There is no "don't delete while iterating pitfall" here, that 
pitfall generally comes up inside`each` based loops and C-style `for`
loops. The problem is probably something inside the `RemoveAssocition()` 
method.

Another possibility is that the `$association` objects returned from 
`GetAssociations()` aren't fully copied when they're passed back: the 
`$association` objects could still be internal data from `$agentConf`. This could be a hidden "don't delete while iterating" pitfall, hard to say without knowing the implementation of `$agentConf` or even what its interface is.

Also, you're missing a sigil on `agentConf` in your second loop but 
that's probably just a typo.

Answer (score 2):

What sort of "weird results" are you getting?  The code you posted has no obvious problems in it (you aren't changing `@associationsToRemove` while iterating over it, so "don't delete from a list you're iterating over" doesn't apply), so I'm inclined to suspect that the actual problem is in `agentConf->RemoveAssociation`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use hash approach like this,

```
my %h = map {$_ => 1 } @agentConfAssociationDeletionsList;
if (exists $h{$agentConfAssociationDeletionsList}) {
   delete  $h{$agentConfAssociationDeletionsList}; # like that
}
```

Comment: Using a hash is more efficient than grepping an array, but your `if ... delete` doesn't do anything similar to his original code.

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of the original list, and iterate through the copy when deleting.

Comment: -1: That's what he's already doing: making a second list containing items of the original list that are to be deleted and then iterating over the copy.